# pocket sphinx android demo 4.4

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

Pocket sphinx android demo runs fine on LG l39c android 4.1. Will not run on LG l34c Android 4.4

"Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000365 (code=0), thread 5046 (cketsphinx.demo)"

Also having problem with TTS never calling onInit (wait does not help)

Again both work fine on LG l39c android 4.1. Anyone having these problems with 4.4? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Speak and wait for completion within create method was the problem. Worked 4.1